# my windows phone is locket

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-535

my windows phone is locket for 1386071 MINUTES SO WHAT CAN I DO TO BREAK THIS LOCKE PLEASE HELP ME MISTAKENLY I ENTERED WRONG PASSWORD AND NOW IT SHOWING ME TO WAIT FOR 1386071 MINUTES

Comment: Kindly see the related question. It may solve your problem